# orbeon integration with Java EE Application

Tags: webforms, orbeon

Following are my requirement
1. I would like to **integrate** the **dynamic web from** created with **Orbeon Web Form** with the existing Java EE Application.

For example
I have created the **Registration Form** using Orbeon Web Form based on the various customer requirement.
I would like to view this dynamic form in my existing Java EE application.

1. Can I integrate Orbeon Web Form into the existing Java EE application
   a.  If the integration is possible how will the user session get maintained.
   b. How can I access the **DATA** saved by **Orbeon** to generate the report**strong text**, OR use the same **DATA** by other Java EE module.
2. Can I change the **default DB schema** provided by **Orbeon**?

Answer (score 0):

1. A few links to the documentation which might be useful:

   - http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/integration
   - http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/proxying-orbeon-forms

   The most robust way right now is to put your app and Orbeon Forms side by side, and use URLs to navigate between the two sides.

   Ideally we would like to have a API to integrate forms within arbitrary pages, and that's a feature on our roadmap:

   http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/projects/orbeon-forms-roadmap#TOC-Integration

   a. Session: this depends on your container and container settings. Some containers allow sharing the session between apps, some not.

   b. You can access the data via the [persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api).
2. Do you mean the MySQL or Oracle database schema? Not sure what you mean by "change", but I guess the answer is no: Orbeon Forms assumes a certain database schema at this point. But you can implement your own [persistence layer](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api).